# Distinction between Chemistry and Alchemy in Arabic and Farsi languages

Tags: etymology, language-change, arabic, persian

According to Wikipedia, in Europe the semantic distinction between the rational science of *chimia* and the occult *alchimia* arose in the early 18th century. So it seems like there was a need to separate these terms with the advancement of scientific practices and the term *chemistry* (with the Arabic article "al-" dropped) came to refer to the scientific practice while *alchemy* came to refer to the older non-scientific practice.

Turkish language in 19th century followed a different path by shifting the meaning of a completely different esoteric practice, *sīmiya*<sup>1</sup> ([letter magic](http://www.muslimphilosophy.com/ik/Muqaddimah/Chapter6/Ch_6_28.htm)), to be used in place of *esoteric/old chemistry* and by keeping the word *kīmiya* as the *scientific/modern chemistry*.

I am wondering if similar semantic changes/shifts happened in Arabic and Farsi languages, but could not find any information since I do not speak/read these languages and the online sources I found regarding the etymology of the word mostly focus on European languages.

---

<sup>1</sup> "Sīmiya" (derived from Ancient Greek sema σήμα: "sign", "symbol") is etymologically unrelated to "kīmiya" (either derived from the ancient Egyptian khem/khm, meaning "blackness" or derived from the Greek χημεία, meaning "cast together").

Comment: I don't have enough information for an answer, but here's a start: in Farsi, *alchemy* is کیمیا (*kīmiya*) and *chemistry* is شیمی (*shimi*) - my assumption here is that *shimi* was borrowed from French (*la chimie*). Just given that, we can guess what the story might be - they kept the old word for the old practices, and borrowed a new (European) word for the new.  The story in Arabic is more mysterious to me.  *Alchemy* seems to be خيمياء (*khīmiya*) and *chemistry* is كيمياء (*kīmiya*).

Answer (score 5):

*Kimiya* (کیمیا) is the Persian word for the attempt of turning tin and copper to silver or gold, or finding the elixir.

Today in Persian, *Kimiya* is only used in a metaphoric sense in the literature for *unreachable*, and *shimi* (شیمی) derived from the French *la chimie* is used to refer to the scientific branch.